# Como exibir o teclado completo Android (texto + numérico)?

Tags: android

Eu implementei um componente de máscaras para um campo texto no meu Aplicativo (https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText/issues).

Funciona muito bem, mas me deparei com um problema que no EditText normal não acontece.

Eu preciso que neste caso seja digitado a informação de placa de veículo cujo formato atual é AAA9999 (vai mudar com a nova placa do Mercosul), mas o problema que estou tendo também se aplicará no novo formato.

O teclado é exibido normalmente, porém quando mudo para o modo "Numeric" e um número é digitado, ele volta automaticamente para o "Alpha". Isso é ruim, pois se preciso digitar 4 números, eu preciso acionar o "Numeric" a cada novo número.

Este efeito não ocorre no EditText padrão.

Como faço para manter o "Numeric" acionado via código ou quando abrir o teclado, fixar o "Numeric"?

Comment: Já aconteceu isso comigo porem no html, e até onde consegui analisar isso depende do teclado do celular, em alguns acontecia e em outros não, então aparentemente não tem como resolver.

Comment: Se não houver jeito, terei que deixar se usar o componente. Ele me ajuda muito, pois abstraio a validação e retirada de caracteres especiais e espaço no campo.

Comment: Não consigo avaliar, pois não há informação o suficiente nem código.